# PHP set Hash isn't the same as Checked hash with Swift app

Tags: php, mysql, sql, swift, hash

I'm trying to set up hashing for passwords with PHP, and my code to set the passwords is:

```
$user = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hashed = hash("md5", $pass);
$sql = "UPDATE Users set password=" . $hashed . " where email=" . email;
```

which will set the password to the hashed version, as I want.
But when I try to check, using:

```
$user = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hashed = hash("md5", $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users where email=" . $user . " and password=" . $hashed;
```

with the exact same inputs, the code doesn't return anything.  Does anyone know why? I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using a Swift app to do the posting.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$pass` and `$hashed` are identical in both cases and/or how they differ? This code should actually fail with an SQL syntax error as is, so I'll assume this is not your *actual* code. Also, don't use MD5 for hashing passwords, use the `password_hash` API.

Comment: @Ealau see my answer, if it solve your problem don't forget check as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hashed = hash("md5", $pass);
$sql = "UPDATE Users set password='" . $hashed . "' where email='" . email . "'";


$user = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hashed = hash("md5", $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users where email='" . $user . "' and password='" . $hashed . ''';
```

Answer (score 0):

Both SQL statements are missing quotes around both strings.  I don't see the mysqli_* or PDO code to actually execute the $sql statements.